# C# Number of characters in string with numbers

Tags: c#, string, numbers, string-length

I have **list of strings** - sList with numeric values (10,20...) and I want to find out number of it -> 10 returns 2.

I tried `sList[i].Length` but it didn't work.

Comment: Could you please be more clear? How the list looks like? are you able to show some code that you are using?

Comment: You mean you want it to return 2 as that's the length of the string or you want it to return the actual value e.g. 10 in this case?

Comment: Which string in the list do you want the length of? All the strings, just one element, ?

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @un-lucky `string[] s = this.Kod.Split('.');` -> values like 10.4.20 so I split It to array with values 10,4,20 than 'var sList = s.ToList();' so I convert it to list with strings

Comment: @sr28 I want it to return 2 as that's length of the string

Comment: @TonySixx - what do you mean doesn't work? Please give sample data and expected result for that data

Comment: @TonySixx  sList[i].ToString().Length

Comment: If sList is a list of strings then .Length should work. Please show the code for the creation and filling of sList.

Comment: @Maverick It seems that works, thanks:)

Comment: Do you mean `2` is the *max* list item length?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew No, if there is value "100" I want to return 3, if value "20" I want return 2 and so on.. I want return length of string

Comment: Then it is such a basic question, you could easily check it at MSDN. `String.Length`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I've checked it but they have example:
`string characters = "abc\u0000def";`
`Console.WriteLine(characters.Length);    // Displays 7`

So it count only letters in string and I want to count numbers too.

Comment: @TonySixx: The `\u0000` is **1 `null` character**. The string has no numbers. See https://ideone.com/CC0mRW. See [MSDN explanation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.string.length(v=vs.110).aspx): *The Length property returns 7, which indicates that it includes the six alphabetic characters as well as the null character.*

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew aha okay thanks for clarification

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the list is a list of strings then `.Length` should work. Otherwise you can try this.

```
sList[i].ToString().Length
```

Comment: If `sList[i]` is a string, then `ToString()` is not necessary.